# Will the timezone be converted across geographical areas?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain, domain-controller, timezone

I'm using Active directory in Windows server 2008 R2. My domain is in a particular timezone and my client say X is in another timezone. Now I have implemented certain restrictions that X cannot logon to any workstation for a particular time. I have implemented these restrictions in my domain controller. Since the client is in another time zone, how will the changes be reflected?